# Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

Currently learning native JS and trying to create an interactive menu.

I'm trying to run a function once the menuBtn has been clicked but I have the following error in the console.

```
undefined is not a function
```

is the global function the issue here?

```
(function () {
        'use strict';

        var menuBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-nav');

        menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        }, false);

}());
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn-nav">
    <span></span>
    <span>Menu</span>
    <span></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Check that menuBtn isn't null/undefined

Comment: do you have your button inside your `html` ?

Comment: @MatthewLock—if the code gets beyond the assignment (and maybe it doesn't), *menuBtn* must be a NodeList. In a browser that doesn't support [*getElementsByClassName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname), an error will be thrown when attempting to call it. If it does support *getElementsByClassName*, then it will return a NodeList of zero or more nodes.

Comment: What's wrong with using strict mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to add an event listener to a NodeList. You need to get a single element.

`var menuBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-nav')[0];`

Comment: @user1381806 If you are sure there will only be a single instance of it, you can assign it an `id` attribute. Then select it using `document.getElementById`